# Como eu faço pra dar Enter e Executar meu button PESQUISA

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei um programa que tem o campo Busca Cliente que carrega os Clientes na listView.. Quero fazer a buscar preenchendo o TextBox e Apertando a Tecla Enter

Comment: Adicionando um action(ou listener, não sei como se chama em c#) no componente para monitorar quando o botão for pressionado?

Comment: `EventHandler`, @diegofm. Mas o termo comum é listener mesmo.

Comment: Como uma busca no google... digito no campo e aperto Enter.. Sem precisar clicar com o mouse ou Tab para selecionar o button

Comment: resolveu seu problema ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Modo 1

Você pode utilizar o evento `KeyDown`.
Ao invés de utilizar o código da tecla, faça uso da [enumeração das teclas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        ExecutarBusca();
}
```

### Modo 2

Outra alternativa - fazer uso da propriedade [`AcceptButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx).
O botão que for atribuído a esta propriedade, será executado automaticamente ao se pressionar a tecla Enter.

Por código:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.AcceptButton = btnPesquisar;
}
```

Ou pela interface:

[image: AcceptButton]

Answer (score 0):

utilize o evento KeyPress do textbox

```
  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
       if (e.KeyChar == 13)
       {
          //Executa  a pesquisa
       }
  }
```

uma outra opção, que eu utilizo, é o TextChanged junto a um timer, que a pesquisa é feita automaticamente ao preencher o textbox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerPesquisa.Enabled = false;
    timerPesquisa.Enabled = true;
}

private void timerPesquisa_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerPesquisa.Enabled = false;
    //Executa a pesquisa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetDefault(Button myDefaultBtn)
{
   this.AcceptButton = myDefaultBtn;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyChar == 13)
{
btnPesquisar.PerformClick(); //ele irá simular um clique no botão.
}
}